# Widgets.py in Interactive Bokeh Apps

Tags: python, flask, bokeh

My goal is to running a simple interactive Bokeh Apps.

```
#import libraries
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import TextInput, Button, Paragraph
from bokeh.layouts import layout

#create widgets
text_input=TextInput(value="World")
button=Button(label="Generate Text")
output=Paragraph()

def update():
    output.text="Hello " + text_input.value

button.on_click(update)
lay_out=layout([[button,text_input],[output]])
curdoc().add_root(lay_out)
```

I run my file by typing

```
python -m bokeh serve widgets.py
```

The Bokeh Server starts running ...

```
2017-06-14 17:22:26,293 Starting Bokeh server version 0.12.5
2017-06-14 17:22:26,309 Starting Bokeh server on port 5006 with applications at
paths ['/widgets']
2017-06-14 17:22:26,309 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 7804
```

Then I go to the web browser with url: http://localhost:5006/widgets

Nothing happened. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That error is telling you that there is an exception in the code that runs when someone loads (`GET`s) the root (`/`) page. You'll need to work out what that error is to track down the cause. Can you post more details? If not see if you can enable debug logging

Comment: Are you running the bokeh server on the same port as specified in the example? `http://localhost:5006/bkapp`

Comment: @Peter: I found the error: the Flask is rendering "embed.html" which is is currently has not been created. That's why the code has another error: "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: embed.html" Let me work on this. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tornado 4.5 came out after Bokeh 0.12.5, but was incompatible and broke things. My guess is that that is your problem (it fits the description). Bokeh 0.12.6 was released yesterday, and fixed the problem. So assuming this is the situation, you can either:

- upgrade your Bokeh version
- downgrade your Tornado version

Comment: Thank you for your timely advice. I have updated my Bokeh package to 0.12.6. Now I can run my bokeh server.